# Locate Glass's location on Google Map

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

Is it possible to have Glass do a POST on it's current coordinate to the server while running other apps, say, Google Hangout or take a picture?
Is there any example or APIs I can leverage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Goggle Glass GDK, you can use an AsyncTask to to do work. If you are using Mirror-API, then that is a separate app, and it can work simultaneously (see GlassWare Fieldtrip).